# React js: run effects (useEffect) with common concerns synchronously

Tags: reactjs, synchronous, use-effect

I have two effects set up to instantiate some values in my stateless react component. However, I can't seem to access the data set by my first function in my second function.

From my reading it seems that these may be running asynchronously, so it isn't guaranteed when each of the functions will run. **How do I get effects with common concerns to run synchronously when they depend on each others effects?** Alternatively, is there actually a better practice for replacing a `constructor` in a stateless react component?

Relevant code:

```
const [roadTiles, setRoadTiles] = useState([]);

...

useEffect(() => {
    populateRoadTiles(); // calls setRoadTiles() -- console.log shows roadTiles has been set
    populateRoadTileDivs(); // uses roadTiles -- roadTiles is still [] and causes index error
}, [])
```

I searched around for similar questions, but most of the solutions came down to individual bugs in the user's code. Hopefully this better distills the question.

EDIT:

Chaining dependencies seems to be the way to go based on [Daniil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65412296/373196) and the documentation.

However, I'm still running into the same problem. Maybe it's an issue with my logic in populateRoadTiles instead (below). The documentation seems to indicate that set*() functions are also async, so it could make sense that roadTiles is still unset after `populateRoadTiles`.

BUT, with the new dependency structure, `populateRoadTileDivs` is eventually called. This seems to indicate that roadTiles should have been set and triggered the second effect.

```
    const populateRoadTiles = () => {
        const newRoadTiles = new Array(height);
        for (let r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            newRoadTiles[r] = new Array(width);
        }
        for (let r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < width; c++) {
                newRoadTiles[r][c] = (
                    <RoadTile
                        onClick={() => getNeighbors(r, c)}
                        type={RoadTileType.EMPTY}
                    />
                );
            }
        }
        setRoadTiles(newRoadTiles);
        console.log(newRoadTiles); // populated array
        console.log(roadTiles); // []
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `useEffect` has [`dependency`] or has not `[]` === `componentDidMount`.

React run the effect after its the dependency changed.

```
const [roadTiles, setRoadTiles] = useState([]);
const [roadTilesDivs, setRoadTilesDivs] = useState([]);

...

useEffect(() => {
    populateRoadTiles(); // calls setRoadTiles() -- console.log shows roadTiles has been set
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    populateRoadTileDivs(); // uses roadTiles -- roadTiles is still [] and causes index error
}, [roadTiles]) // <- add dependency here
```

if you want to log state keep it variable

```
    setRoadTiles(newRoadTiles); 
    console.log(newRoadTiles); // not actual, but it will be correct 
    console.log(roadTiles); // [] actual but it's prematurely.
```

Comment: This solution makes sense and matches what I see in the documentation. However, I'm still running into the same issue. I updated my original post with more details.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your updated code yet. But I don't know you task well.

Comment: I think the issue may be that roadTiles is initially updated via `useState([])`. If I add the following code to populateRoadTileDivs(): ```console.log(roadTiles); if (!roadTiles || !roadTiles.length) { return; }``` I see that originally roadTiles is an empty array, then populated on populateRoadTileDivs()'s second invocation. Is this an accurate understanding of the roadTiles dependency in useEffect?

Comment: Do you ensure about  'width' and 'height' ?

Comment: Yes. Width and height are set and I'm seeing the grid populated using the logic above. It feels a bit like a hack, though.

Comment: Can you reproduce the simple code example which show trouble in codesandbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226304/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-justian-meyer).

Answer (score 0):

use `useMemo` as `Reactjs` try This

```
useMemo(() => {
    populateRoadTiles(); // calls setRoadTiles() -- console.log shows roadTiles has been set
    populateRoadTileDivs(); // uses roadTiles -- roadTiles is still [] and causes index error
}, [])
```

### API:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

### Example:
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usememo-hook